# Creating a user web control tied with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, controls

I'm not even sure it's possible as I have not been able to find any documentation on the matter, but my goal is this: In Visual Studio 2012 (I imagine the process would probably apply to 2010 as well), I need to integrate my JavaScript web control into Visual Studio. Now, basically, I need a control in the toolbox which would generate following code when dropped on a form:
In .ASPX file:

```
<table id="gridView1">

</table>
```

In JavaScript file of the same name (create it if needed, append if it already exists):

```
gridView1 = new GridView(tableOfContents, "gridView1", "checkbox");
```

The JS code in a separate file would be ideal, but having it embended in  tags works too. Now, as you might have noticed, there are currently 3 arguments in the object's constructor: contents is first, then ID of the table, and then an optional argument (there's 4 of those). So, the last thing I need is for these arguments to be changeable using 'properties' editor of Visual Studio. That means that when I right-click the control in the designer and click 'Properties', I can change 'name' of the object, toggle between "checkbox" and "multiline" options of multiselect and whatnot, with these changes reflecting in the JS code.

I also can't use server-side events as I need this element to be accessible offline.

Now as I said, I do doubt that this is even possible in Visual Studio. However, I am hoping that there is something I have overlooked. If you have any suggestions, pointers or even know of documentation / book to solve this, please, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that you ask for is definitely possible.
You can get started by reading

[How to: Use Custom ASP.NET Server Controls in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366537%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

How to set properties:

[Server Control Collection Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178654%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Control what a developer see at design time

[ASP.NET Control Designers Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh45wzs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

As to tie these to javascript, just like you would do on any page or control

[ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx)

Comment: All right, so far everything I needed seems to work and what doesn't is just me being an idiot. Thank you for taking your time and linking these articles.

Comment: There are quite a few hickups when you start building custom server controls. Glad to help! :-)